# How to recall the previous info submitted and change some fields only for the next submit

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

In my google form to register for an event, users may need to register a few times for the different members of their group (e.g. family members) but some of the information is the same e.g. address, house phone. Is there a way to recall the last record submitted so that the user can just change the name to register the next person, without having to re-type the address, house phone etc?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is not possible in Google Forms. Best you can do is to redesign your form in such a way that submitter would be able to attach also fellow members in one go. Once data are in the spreadsheet, form submissions can be reshaped to any possible form you can think of with formulas.